# Python CSV - Double-double quotes being written into CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write some data into a csv file. I want only the middle column to have quotes in the csv file. I start out with the data saved in a array over arrays. Here are a few entries printed out:

```
['1', '"For Those About To Rock We Salute You"', 'Album']
['2', '"Balls to the Wall"', 'Album']
['3', '"Restless and Wild"', 'Album']
['4', '"Let There Be Rock"', 'Album']
['5', '"Big Ones"', 'Album']
['6', '"Jagged Little Pill"', 'Album']
...
```

As you can see the only the middle column has quotes. However when I write this to a csv file this is what I get:

```
1,""For Those About To Rock We Salute You"",Album
2,""Balls to the Wall"",Album
3,""Restless and Wild"",Album
4,""Let There Be Rock"",Album
5,""Big Ones"",Album
6,""Jagged Little Pill"",Album
...
```

Everything is fine except that middle column! I have double-double quotes!

I have a function that takes the data (which is saved in an array of arrays), and writes it into a csv file. I looked into the `QUOTE_NONE` method but that doesn't seem to work...

```
file_data = ...
def write_node_csv():
    with open("./csv_files/albums.csv", mode='w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar="\"")
        for data in file_data:
            writer.writerow(data)
    csv_file.close()
```

So basically I'm expecting this:

```
1,"For Those About To Rock We Salute You",Album
2,"Balls to the Wall",Album
3,"Restless and Wild",Album
4,"Let There Be Rock",Album
5,"Big Ones",Album
6,"Jagged Little Pill",Album
...
```

but I'm getting this:

```
1,""For Those About To Rock We Salute You"",Album
2,""Balls to the Wall"",Album
3,""Restless and Wild"",Album
4,""Let There Be Rock"",Album
5,""Big Ones"",Album
6,""Jagged Little Pill"",Album
...
```

Comment: Try `quotechar=''` in the `writer` (you shouldn't need the `escapechar`)

Comment: @AChampion it still gives the same result...

Comment: I can't repeat your problem... I'll post my test code below. Can you post your original data (csv)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demonstration of getting your results:

```
In []:
data = """'1', '"For Those About To Rock We Salute You"', 'Album'
'2', '"Balls to the Wall"', 'Album'
'3', '"Restless and Wild"', 'Album'
'4', '"Let There Be Rock"', 'Album'
'5', '"Big Ones"', 'Album'
'6', '"Jagged Little Pill"', 'Album'"""

import csv
with StringIO(data) as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, quotechar="'", skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

Out[]:
['1', '"For Those About To Rock We Salute You"', 'Album']
['2', '"Balls to the Wall"', 'Album']
['3', '"Restless and Wild"', 'Album']
['4', '"Let There Be Rock"', 'Album']
['5', '"Big Ones"', 'Album']
['6', '"Jagged Little Pill"', 'Album']

In []:
with StringIO(data) as fin, StringIO() as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, quotechar="'", skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(fout, quotechar='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerows(reader)
    contents = fout.getvalue()
print(contents)

Out[]:
1,"For Those About To Rock We Salute You",Album
2,"Balls to the Wall",Album
3,"Restless and Wild",Album
4,"Let There Be Rock",Album
5,"Big Ones",Album
6,"Jagged Little Pill",Album
```

Comment: by specifying the `quotechar` instead of the `escapechar` it's working perfectly! Thanks!